# Spinlaunch Safety

Tags: launch, design

How could the Spinlaunch concept ever be made so that, in the event of an anomaly where it is released at the wrong angle, it wouldn't obliterate a small town or city center?

Launch sites at Cape Canaveral and Vandenberg have range safety requirements for traditional rockets, requiring abort systems to detonate the vehicle if it goes off course.

Does anyone know how it is proposed to cover this hazard for the Spinlaunch concept?  I could see surrounding the launcher, all but a small exit slot, with a mountain of concrete, but the energy involved seems so high to be infeasible to guarantee safety.

Comment: I wonder how much damage it could actually do. 

I don’t think it would be a massive amount, because most angles would either just send it into the dirt, into the sky, and only a few would actually go sideways a large ammount.

Comment: The most compelling defense of the safety of SpinLaunch is the very low probability that it will ever work.

Comment: @Topcode, if they truly had something that could put a ballistic payload into orbit, I think the military would instantly buy it from them as the greatest weapon tech since rockets.  Tweak the trajectory slightly and it reenters the atm.  Also, at 17000 mph (orbital speed) and say 500 lb, its kinetic energy is about 1.5 Megatons, so even if it "hit the dirt" it would destroy the launch site.

Comment: @RC_23 spin launch could never go into orbit without extra propellant. Even if it could go as fast as you want it would be suborbital or on an escape trajectory. Yeah hitting the dirt would be a big boom, but also be local. Wouldn’t go off and smash into anything that’s really that important.

Comment: There is the engineering benefit of this being the *ground* system: the factor of safety can be enormous because it doesn't have to fly

Comment: @RC_23 I think you're massively overestimating the the amount of kinetic energy involved here. The kinetic energy of a 250kg mass travelling at ~7500m/s is 7GJ, which is about 1.7 tons (not megatons) of TNT.

Comment: Considering the launch, assuming the entire "upper stage" is ~2.5 tonnes and is released at ~2.2km/s, then the kinetic energy is ~6GJ (1.4 tons TNT). Using very rough assumptions (RP1/LOX, 2000kg propellant means ~560kg RP1, assume an energy density of 40MJ/kg, same as kerosene), the energy in the fuel is ~22GJ, several times the kinetic energy, meaning that Spinlaunch actually has much less energy than a fully fuelled conventional rocket would have. Also, I expect slamming into a solid steel vacuum chamber wall at ~2.2km/s will negate the need for any sort of range safety explosive device....

Comment: You are right.  I lost track of my prefixes converting to Joules and then TNT.  Only a factor of a million off....

Comment: I still see a safety concern, as it can be flung towards a populated area (say Titusville, FL) and the launch controllers would have no time to react like they would if a rocket went off course. Or even if they did react, there's nothing they could do about it

Comment: I would assume that it wouldn't really be possible to fling it the wrong way - any mistimed release will result in the rocket slamming into the side of the vacuum chamber. Even ignoring the loss in velocity in penetrating the wall, what was once the rocket is now just a ball of flaming gas and very un-aerodynamic fragments of metal which will very quickly lose momentum through drag and not make it very far. While a shower of hot high velocity fragments is bad news for anyone in the local vicinity, I wouldn't expect much of the rocket to get very far.

Comment: There seems to be some question about what you (OP) mean.  I think you're asking about the situation where a payload & upper stage come through the side of the launcher, such as if they became detached from the rotating mechanism prematurely, right?

Comment: If so, then a very simple solution is to build the launcher underground rather than above-ground.  "Simple" might be overstating it, but having not looked too closely at the engineering given the scale of the launcher, heck, it might even be more cost-effective to just build it underground anyways.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at how the spinlaunch launcher is designed you'll see that the 'muzzle' is a fairly tightly collimated tube that points (at the present time) straight up. I'm not sure how a launch vehicle could be 'flung' in any unwanted direction- a misfire might obliterate the launcher, but if the launch is successful the rocket will only go in one direction.

To account for an underpowered launch there would need to be a range of cleared land or sea, just as there is for conventional launches, with enough distance to allow the launch vehicle to fall safely to earth (or sea). Range safety explosives could serve to convert such a misfire into smaller bits that would slow relatively quickly. Once the second stage ignites things would progress in a more conventional manner...